# How to stop ajax loader

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this implemented:

```
$('#loader').hide()  // hide it initially
.ajaxStart(function() {
                        $('#loader').show();
                      })
.ajaxStop(function() {
                        $('#loader').hide();
                     });
```

And this is working perfectly when I'm using ajax method. But I want to be able to disable ajax loader in this circumstantecs.

```
    setInterval(function(){
      //I need to disable loader in here
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "live_top_5.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) 
            {
                               //do something
            }
            });     
},10000);
```

Problem is that my loader is covering full screen and I want to disable it for this certain ajax call because I am refreshing this content every 10 sec. Is that possible? To disable ajax loader for the certain ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an option for that, check this additional note:

> If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to
>   false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

**Edit: add the global parameter on the calls that shouldn't fire the event**

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "live_top_5.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            global: false,
            success: function(response) 
            {
                               //do something
            }
            });
```

Comment: so solution on my code would be like what? I can't find that global option that you are talking about

Comment: You're welcome. You can put my post as problem solver to thank me :D

Comment: yea I will don't worry..just needed to wait a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
   setInterval(function(){
  setTimeout((function(){ $('#loader').hide();}),200);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "live_top_5.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) 
        {
                           //do something
        }
        });     
},10000);
```

**or you can use the flag in initialization**

```
var allowed = true;
$('#loader').hide()  // hide it initially
.ajaxStart(function() {
                  if(allowed)  $('#loader').show();
                  })
.ajaxStop(function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                 });
```

and in ajax check for that

```
  setInterval(function(){
  allowed = false;
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "live_top_5.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) 
        {
                 allowed = true;          //do something
        }
        });     
   },10000);
```